# How do I stop a process controlled by a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Java application which launches another application with some parameters. The Java should be able to continue meanwhile and kill the other application after user input.
Reading up on this I found out I should use `Thread.Interupt()` because `Thread.Stop()` is deprecated.
On your thread it would throw a InterruptedExection. So what I have is:

```
public class ProcessExecutor extends Object implements Runnable {
    private volatile int id;
    private String message;
    private Process proc = null;

    public ProcessExecutor(int id, String message) {

        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int GetId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String[] cmd = new String[4];
            cmd[0] = "path to some app";
            cmd[1] = id;
            cmd[2] = message;

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            proc = rt.exec(cmd);

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            String line=null;

            while ((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: " + line);
            }

            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();

            System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: Exited with error code " + exitVal);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: stopping");

            if (proc != null) {             
                proc.destroy();
                proc = null;
            }           
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which is handled by:

```
private List<Thread> activeProccesses = new ArrayList<Thread>();

public void StartProcess(int id, String message) {
    System.out.println("StartProcess: id=" + id + ", message='" + message + "'");

    StopAllProcesses();

    ProcessExecutor proc = new ProcessExecutor(id, message);
    Thread procThread = new Thread(proc);
    activeProccesses.add(procThread);
    procThread.start();
}

public void StopAllProcesses() {
    System.out.println("Stopping all processes");

    Iterator<Thread> it = activeProccesses.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Thread procThread = it.next();

        if (procThread.isAlive()) {
            procThread.interrupt();             
        }

        it.remove();
    }

    System.out.println("Stopping all processes: done");        
}
```

How ever the `procThread.interrupt()` gets executed but the `catch(InterruptedException ex)` never hits.

Why is this and how can I fix this?

**Edit: The conclusion**

Turned out the Thread was blocked by the `input.readLine()` inorder to stop that I had to directly stop the `Process` which then unblocked the `input.readLine()`.

```
public class ProcessExecutor extends Thread {
    private volatile int id;
    private String message;
    private volatile Process proc = null;

    public ProcessExecutor(int id, String message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int GetId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void StopProc() {
        if (proc != null) {
            proc.destroy();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String[] cmd = new String[4];
            cmd[0] = "path to some app";
            cmd[1] = id;
            cmd[2] = message;

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            proc = rt.exec(cmd);

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            String line=null;

            while ((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: " + line);
            }

            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            proc = null;

            System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: Exited with error code " + exitVal);          
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: exception: " + e.toString());
            StopProc();
        }
    }
}

private List<ProcessExecutor> activeProccesses = new ArrayList<ProcessExecutor>();

public void StartProcess(int id, String message) {
    System.out.println("StartProcess: id=" + id + ", message='" + message + "'");

    StopAllProcesses();

    ProcessExecutor proc = new ProcessExecutor(id, message);
    activeProccesses.add(proc);
    proc.start();
}

public void StopAllProcesses() {
    System.out.println("Stopping all processes");

    Iterator<ProcessExecutor> it = activeProccesses.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        ProcessExecutor proc = it.next();

        proc.StopProc();
        it.remove();
    }

    System.out.println("Stopping all processes: done");        
}
```

Comment: A thread and a process are two different things. To kill a process, call its `destroy `method. Interrupting the thread that waits for the end of a process won't kill the process.

Comment: If a InterruptedException is being thrown, then I can kill the process via proc.destroy();. But why is the InterruptedException not being thrown?

Comment: Probably because the thread is blocked reading the lines from the process input stream, and this blocking call is not interruptible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment. I think the only way to interrupt a thread blocked reading a line is to kill the process from which the thread reads. Just as the only solution to interrupt a thread blocked reading on a socket is to close the socket.

Add a method to your thread that destroys the process.

Comment: Correctly, this is what I just did and it works :) Updating the question with the solution for future reference.

Comment: Blocking the sender process to stop the receivers? That's a terrible solution. At the very least you can send an "end of stream" so that the receivers cleanly exits. The best solution of course would be not to block indefinitely in the first place.

Comment: The read methods are all blocking methods. There is no other option than to block indefinitely. If the process can be stopped more gracefully, it should of course be. But that's process-specific.

Comment: And, anyway, the OP wants to destroy the process when the thread is interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly check for the interrupted condition in your ProcessExecutor; an InterruptedException will not be thrown automatically. Something like this:

```
public class ProcessExecutor extends Object implements Runnable {

  public void run() {
    try {
       //other code....

       while ((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: " + line);
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
              // We've been interrupted!
              throw new InterruptedException("....");
            }
       }
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: stopping");
}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html for more details.

Comment: Just tried it out and has the same problem. Thread is blocked in readLine.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupting threads only works if they are in specific states, usually it's done during `wait()` calls that are done when not actively processing data.

If you want the thread to die in between `readLine()` calls you can check `interrupted()` in the while check instead of using a try-catch.

**Edit:** the best way to solve your problem would be

```
while (true)
{
    if (input.ready())
    {
        line = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: " + line);
    } else {
        try { Thread.sleep(100); } // time to wait in ms
        catch (InterruptedException ie) { break; }
    }
}
```

Since `ready()` actually checks for a single character you should use successive `read()` instead of `readLine()`, but if you write on the stream a line at a time there should be no difference this way. The time to wait for is clearly arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest more graceful way to stop a thread. In the run method, you have following code

```
 while ((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: " + line);
            }
```

in `ProcessExecutor`, add a boolean field accompanied by its getter and setter.

```
private Boolean stop = false;
```

and check the same flag in while condition.

```
while (((line=input.readLine()) != null) && !stop) {
                    System.out.println("ProcessExecutor: " + line);
                }
```

in `StopAllProcesses()` method, set  `stop=true` on   `ProcessExecutor` instances . this will result into `run()` method returning and gracefully stopping the thread.

Comment: This is for all intents and purposes equal to Jeremiah Orr's solution, and shares the same flaw: it doesn't exit the thread if it's blocked trying to read.

Comment: Yes! OP should mention the _blocking_ condition explicitly. Thats what OP wants I guess.

Comment: I didn't know that readLine was blocking it. I only saw that the thread was not stopping.